# How to create a pull up view in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit, gesture

Dear Fellow Developers,

How would I (or you) go about creating a view that can be slid up, like Apple has done in the new iOS 12 Stocks app? I've been searching if there's native support for this but haven't found it yet. If you haven't used it, it's a News view that can be pulled up in front of the stocks information and it has its own content. It can naturally be also pushed down again.

I would prefer to use Apple's implementations if they exist instead of 3rd party.

Most of the similar questions were at least 5 years old so I'm wondering what the current options are.

Answer: I followed the instructions of the accepted answer created my own implementation:

1. Create a view that should get raised up
2. Create another view as top slice of view number 1 to be the place where you grab the view
3. Add a PanGestureRecognizer and hook it up to the view number 2
4. Create view number 3 in view number 2 to be the small icon as seen in the stock app view
5. Add rounding of corners and shadowing to view number 1

[image: Stocks image]

[image: Ready implementation.]

Comment: You could just use a third party library such as https://github.com/marioiannotta/pullupcontroller

Comment: Not sure why this was considered too broad or a -1 question... Just checking if there was a preferred method. It's definitely not very broad since the question is about a single view type.

Comment: Ugh... can't even delete it although the community condemns it.

Comment: Would you share (i.e. github gist) the code of your own implementation (based on answer as you said)

Comment: @HassanTareq sorry, I don't have access to that codebase anymore.

Comment: I shared my universal solution. Try this https://github.com/multimediasuite/SweetCurtain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update: For iOS15 and above, Apple has introduced [UISheetPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller). Have a look!**

Well I am not acquainted with the iOS 12 Stocks app. But here's how you can do it.

Create a view that recognizes pan gesture. Track the pan gesture and update the the origin y of the view that slides up accordingly.